# Непредвиденное появление: ). 11 строка. Как исправить?

Tags: bat

Нужно чтоб просто отображалось echo Program Files (x86) (11 строка) но это выдаст ошибку как исправить !

```
@echo off

set pf="C:\Program Files\WinRar\WinRar.exe"
set pf86="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRar\WinRar.exe"

if EXIST %pf% (
    echo Program Files
    echo YES
    ) else (
        if EXIST %pf86% (
            echo Program Files (x86)
            echo YES
            ))
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Непредвиденное появление: ).

Comment: В кавычки выводимую строку возьмите.

Comment: @andreymal Я хочу без кавычек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@echo off

set pf="C:\Program Files\WinRar\WinRar.exe"
set pf86="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRar\WinRar.exe"

if EXIST %pf% (
    echo Program Files
    echo YES
    ) else (
        if EXIST %pf86% (
            echo Program Files ^(x86^)
            echo YES
            ))
```

Скорее всего вот это `echo Program Files (x86)` нарушает структуру скобок управляющих конструкций